# Fast text scrolling in VS Code

Tags: scroll, visual-studio-code

I am testing out Visual Studio Code on macOS, and was wondering if there is a key combination for faster scrolling?

I would need this, for example, to go quickly from an early part of the code to a part towards the end of the file.

*e.g.* in Emacs when I hold up/down-arrow and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, the scroll speed increases noticeably; VS Code actually stops scrolling with the same command. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+arrow will get me to the start / end of the file, but I could not find a combination that merely speeds things up and nothing in the [keyboard shortcuts](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf) looked helpful.

Version is 1.21.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not available, but is an open issue. You can follow the progress here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24344

Answer (score 52):

Update: Since [v1.31](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_31#_fast-scrolling) you can now press <kbd>Alt</kbd> to enable fast scrolling. It works by activating `editor.fastScrollSensitivity`.

Comment: I believe OP wanted a keyboard-only solution (even though the issue in the accepted answer is about the mouse scroll),  But this answer is simply the direct version of the accepted one - which is no longer valid on its own.

Comment: This is wonderful! Am I correct that I can't change "alt" from it? I want to use "ctrl" + wheel, like I always do in other IDEs. I don't like getting used to alt as well now, argh

Comment: @BAERUS Same :(

Answer (score 32):

There is

```
"editor.mouseWheelScrollSensitivity": 1,  // or any number
```

You can scroll by pages too:

<kbd>PageDown</kbd> or <kbd>PageUp</kbd>

Comment: Combine this with pressing Alt and you're gold!

Comment: Not true, you can set it to read numbers like `0.3` and `2.5`

Comment: @jakob-r Not sure what I meant 4 years ago, you could always set it to various numbers.  I updated the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 23):

Go to File > Preferences > Settings. Search for: mouseWheelScrollSensitivity, change it for 0.01

Answer (score 3):

> in Emacs when I hold up/down-arrow *[...]*

The OP mentioned key strokes as opposed to mouse scrolling.

My solution was at an OS level, *i.e.* lessen the **Key Repeat** and **Delay Until Repeat** settings so that holding the `up` / `down` arrows will scroll much quicker.

*Important note:* This setting will update **all** key presses regardless of the app.

---

If on OSX, this setting can be found in System Preferences under Keyboard, or overwritten directly in the terminal. The following will take effect after a system reboot.

```sh
defaults write -g InitialKeyRepeat -int 10 # normal minimum is 15 (225 ms)
defaults write -g KeyRepeat -int 1 # normal minimum is 2 (30 ms)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Scroll Faster](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EnkelDigital.scroll-faster) extension overrides the `Ctrl+Up/Down` shortcuts to scroll by a user-defined number of lines, rather than VS Code's default of 1. It also adds an option to allow the cursor to be "dragged along" if using the shortcut would cause it to go off-screen.

You can install it by pasting `ext install EnkelDigital.scroll-faster` into the quick switcher (`Ctrl/Cmd+P`).

Comment: THANK YOU sir. it was exactly what i have been looking for! 

faster scrolling, just for crtl+arrow.